# How to use reflection to determine if a class is internal?

Tags: c#, reflection

As the title says, how do you use reflection to check if a class definition is defined as internal?   "typeof(...)" returns certain properties shown below but not whether a class is defined as internal.   Looked on Google but all I could find were lots of articles about running internal or protected methods using reflection.  It's not the methods I'm interested in this case, but the class definition.

```
var type = typeof(Customer);
Assert.IsTrue(type.IsClass);
Assert.That(type.IsAbstract, Is.EqualTo(isAbstract));
Assert.That(type.IsPublic, Is.EqualTo(isPublic));
Assert.That(type.IsPublic, Is.EqualTo(isPublic));
Assert.That(type.IsSealed, Is.EqualTo(isSealed));
Assert.That(type.IsSerializable, Is.EqualTo(isSerializable));
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This is a classic issue. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183.aspx):

> The C# keywords `protected` and `internal` have no meaning in IL and are not used in the Reflection APIs. The corresponding terms in IL are `Family` and `Assembly`. To identify an `internal` method using Reflection, use the `IsAssembly` property. To identify a `protected internal` method, use the `IsFamilyOrAssembly`.

Reflection does not expose a way on `Type` check if it is `internal`, `protected` or `protected internal`.

Comment: I'm not sure the MSDN documentation is accurate, but perhaps I'm wrong. For example, I know `Tuple<>` implements `internal interface ITuple`. The `Type` on this interface has `false` for the aforementioned flags. Tests on my own internal class behave the same.

Comment: Further, `Nested` to me reads as `class A { class B { } }`, where `B` is nested within `A`. The properties the documentation specifically mentions, `IsAssembly`, `IsFamily` are not publicly available on the `Type` object.

Comment: One minor correction: C# `protected internal` corresponds to CLR `FamORAssem` (i.e. visible to anything that is in the same assembly OR a derived type). `FamANDAssem` has no corresponding C# equivalent (except in my dreams).

Comment: @zinglon: Thanks. I did mix it up.

Comment: Primarily thanks to @Jason for the quick and detailed answer.  Thanks to everyone else for the further detail.  Stack Overflow really is the dogs when it comes to getting answers!

Comment: @AnthonyPegram For a non-nested type, i.e. a type that is a direct member of a namespace and not contained in an outer class/struct, there are two levels possible. In reflection they correspond to `IsPublic` and `IsNotPublic` properties. These properties return false for _all_ nested types. For nested types, use properties like `IsNestedFamOrAssem`, `IsNestedPrivate` and so on (all begin with `IsNested...`).

Answer (score 13):

Does the [IsVisible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isvisible.aspx) method give you the value you are looking for?

Comment: IsVisible certainly is an effective way of determining an interface's internal visibility.

Answer (score 10):

Here are some functions guaranteed to give the correct visibility of the type (probably an overkill implementation):

```
bool isPublic(Type t) {
    return
        t.IsVisible
        && t.IsPublic
        && !t.IsNotPublic
        && !t.IsNested
        && !t.IsNestedPublic
        && !t.IsNestedFamily
        && !t.IsNestedPrivate
        && !t.IsNestedAssembly
        && !t.IsNestedFamORAssem
        && !t.IsNestedFamANDAssem;
}

bool isInternal(Type t) {
    return
        !t.IsVisible
        && !t.IsPublic
        && t.IsNotPublic
        && !t.IsNested
        && !t.IsNestedPublic
        && !t.IsNestedFamily
        && !t.IsNestedPrivate
        && !t.IsNestedAssembly
        && !t.IsNestedFamORAssem
        && !t.IsNestedFamANDAssem;
}

// only nested types can be declared "protected"
bool isProtected(Type t) {
    return
        !t.IsVisible
        && !t.IsPublic
        && !t.IsNotPublic
        && t.IsNested
        && !t.IsNestedPublic
        && t.IsNestedFamily
        && !t.IsNestedPrivate
        && !t.IsNestedAssembly
        && !t.IsNestedFamORAssem
        && !t.IsNestedFamANDAssem;
}

// only nested types can be declared "private"
bool isPrivate(Type t) {
    return
        !t.IsVisible
        && !t.IsPublic
        && !t.IsNotPublic
        && t.IsNested
        && !t.IsNestedPublic
        && !t.IsNestedFamily
        && t.IsNestedPrivate
        && !t.IsNestedAssembly
        && !t.IsNestedFamORAssem
        && !t.IsNestedFamANDAssem;
}
```

Comment: It's possible to define internal nested classes. So this won't work in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

Ehh, I'm not quite sure, but e.g.

```
Public Function PublicFriendOrPrivate(t As Type) As String
    If t.IsPublic Then
        Return "Public"
    Else
        If t.IsNotPublic AndAlso t.IsNested Then
            Return "Private"
        Else
            Return "Friend"
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

'Note 'Friend' equals 'Internal' in C#.