# How to check accessibility of C# class/interface/struct/enum during runtime?

Tags: c#

I would like to use a code during runtime to check the accessibility (public/protected/private/internal) of 
a class/interface/struct/enum. The base class Type has only one clear field **IsPublic** for this purpose, what about the rest when it is NOT **public**? e.g.

```
 Type t1 = typeof(MyClass);
 Console.WriteLine("IsPublic: {0}", t1.IsPublic);
```

Comment: Will IsPublic is not return false in that case?

Comment: Take a look to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4971213/how-to-use-reflection-to-determine-if-a-class-is-internal